# Documentation for chef's attribute construct in metadata.rb file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am new to chef and seeing the following code in metadata.rb file for a project handed over to me from someone.

```
attribute 'setup',
   :required => 'required',
   :default => 'internal',
   :format => {
     :category => '1.Global',
     :order => 1,
     :filter => {'all' => {'visible' => 'true'}},
     :form => {'field' => 'select', 'options_for_select' => [
         ['External', 'external'], ['Internal','internal']
       ]
     }
   }
```

I have gone through both https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html and 
https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html but unable to understand most of the non-obvious constructs like category, order, filter, form etc.

Are these not part of the standard chef packages?

Comment: Never seen this, too. Maybe some custom tooling around Chef?

Answer (score 0):

The metadata fields still exist but nothing in the Chef ecosystem ever used them (except maybe old versions of Rightscale but that's not really "Chef ecosystem" anymore). Because of this we remove most of the docs about the feature. You can delete at will most likely, unless you have custom tools that use the data.